# Compile several .scss files with Visual Studio Code

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I try to compile several `.scss` files with Visual Code.

I tried

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "sass",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks" : [
        {   
            "taskName": "Turquoise.scss",
            "args": ["css/colors/turquoise.scss", "css/colors/turquoise.css"]
        },
        {
            "taskName": "Styles.scss",
            "args": ["css/styles.scss", "css/styles.css"]
        }
    ]
}
```

in the `tasks.json` file.

but it is not working. The error is "No configurated generation task"...

My question: How to compile several `.scss` files (without gulp, npm, etc.)

---

## Remark

With

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "sass",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["css/colors/turquoise.scss", "css/colors/turquoise.css"]
}
```

it works. I just want to do the same with several files.

Comment: You can use EasySass extension to automatically build Sass/Scss files after saving.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a main.scss file being compiled by Visual Code and import all your other stylesheets there. Then you'll have as many scss files as you want, but only one compiled scc file (This also will increase performance on your webserver later on, because there's only one http request for a stylesheet)

Comment: I have similar problem and my project has different stylesheets for different parts/services and also some third-party sass files which I don't want to compile on build. So neither one grouped stylesheet or EasySass extension dont solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's not direct answer but I achieved what I think you want by:

1. Installing Live Sass Compiler extension
2. Setting `liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList` to exclude some folders or files (for workspace or globally)
3. Setting keyboard shortcut for `liveSass.command.oneTimeCompileSass`

This way sass is compiled on demand excluding files I don't want to compile.

Live Sass Compiler: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass